# HTTP POST using JSON in Spring Rest

Tags: spring, web-services, rest, spring-mvc, spring-rest

I would like to make a simple HTTP POST using Spring RestTemplate.
the Wesb service accept JSON in parameter for example: `{"name":"mame","email":"email@gmail.com"}`

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {

    final String uri = "url";
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    // Add the Jackson message converter
    restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
    // create request body
    String input = "{   \"name\": \"name\",   \"email\": \"email@gmail.com\" }";
    JsonObject request = new JsonObject();
    request.addProperty("model", input);

    // set headers
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    headers.set("Authorization", "Basic " + "xxxxxxxxxxxx");
    HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(request.toString(), headers);

    // send request and parse result
    ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate
            .exchange(uri, HttpMethod.POST, entity, String.class);

    System.out.println(response);
}
```

When I test this code I got this error:

```
 Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 400 Bad Request
```

when I call webservice with Curl I have correct result:

```
 curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Basic xxxxxxxxxx" --header "Content-Type: application/json" --header "Accept: application/json" -d "{   \"name\": \"name\",   \"email\": \"email@gmail.com\" } " "url"
```

Comment: add the webservice code you are trying to reach and  screenshot of postman or curl expression which is executed correctly...

Comment: I'haven't access to webservice. by using curl I can call ws using this command: curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Basic xxxxxxxxxx" --header "Content-Type: application/json" --header "Accept: application/json" -d "{   \"name\": \"name\",   \"email\": \"email@gmail.com\" }
" "url"

Answer (score 16, accepted):

try to remove `model` from the code, as i can see in your curl request you didn't use model attribute and everything works. try this:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

    final String uri = "url";
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    // Add the Jackson message converter
    restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
    // create request body
    String input = "{\"name\":\"name\",\"email\":\"email@gmail.com\"}";


    // set headers
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    headers.set("Authorization", "Basic " + "xxxxxxxxxxxx");
    HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(input, headers);

    // send request and parse result
    ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate
            .exchange(uri, HttpMethod.POST, entity, String.class);

    System.out.println(response);
}
```

Comment: Can the message converter convert a Java object into json string? Let's say input is an ojbect of type User. User = new User("name", "email@gmail.com");